# hyperref with tilde

Tags: hyperref, urls, tilde

How can I make the tilde appear in the url in the following document? I know that this has been asked many times before but googling has -not- helped me in my case. The following document does not show the tilde in the url.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{letter}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[lowtilde]{url} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\href{http://www.university.edu/~person/index.html}{http://www.university.edu/~person/index.html}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `see url \url{https://www.university.edu/~person/index.html}`?

Comment: What about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBKvo.png) ([code](https://pastebin.com/4TZKdaAG))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is just to use `\(\sim \)`, another is `\textasciitilde`

[image: Demo]

`\href{http://www.university.edu/~person/index.html}{http://www.university.edu/\(\sim \)person/index.html}`

`\href{http://www.university.edu/~person/index.html}{http://www.university.edu/\textasciitilde person/index.html}`